# Error with id on INSERT INTO entity on Doctrine2/Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Since some days, I've a problème with one of my entity.
This entity has its ID to be defined manually (no auto-increment). But when I try to define it, Doctrine return an error on the insert into query :

> DBALException: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO InfosPerso (num, login, nom, prenom, email, societe, adr1, adr2, cp, ville, tel, fax, nichandle, parrain, actif, state, emailvalide, date_creation, id_entite_legale_pays, pays) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "Test", "Hebert", "Donovan", "test@mail.com", "SNCF", "Tempore excepteur nulla molestiae sed temporibus eum officia error illo tempore et amet voluptatum vel modi cupiditate", "Laboriosam eiusmod dolor non saepe incidunt cillum corrupti occaecat dolorem tempore aut quis esse autem", "13001", "Marseille", "0442910000", "0442499569", 0, null, 1, 0, 1, "2015-06-04 11:09:46.000", null, 171]:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 515 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [515] (severity 16) [(null)]

Here my current code :

```
$infosPerso = new InfosPerso();
$infosPerso->setLogin($client->getLogin())
->setParrain($leaderBmcId)
->setNicHandle(0)
->setNom($client->getName())
->setPrenom($client->getFirstname())
->setEmail($client->getEmail())
->setAdr1($client->getAddress())
->setAdr2($client->getComplementaryAddress())
->setCp($client->getZipCode())
->setDateCreation($client->getCreationDate())
->setTel($client->getPhone())
->setFax($client->getFax())
->setVille($client->getCity())
->setPays($client->getCountry())// Entity Pays
->setSociete($client->getCompany()->getLibCompanies())
->setEmailValide(true)
->setState(0)
->setActif(1);
```

And the entity definition for ID :

```
/**
 * @var integer $num
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="num", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
 * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="BizDatasBundle\Database\BMC\InfosPersoIdGenerator")
 */
private $num;
```

The InfosPersoIdGenerator class is defined like that:

```
<?php

namespace BizDatasBundle\Database\BMC;

use Doctrine\ORM\Id\AbstractIdGenerator;


class InfosPersoIdGenerator extends AbstractIdGenerator
{
    public function generate(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em, $entity)
    {
        $maxId = $em->createQueryBuilder('ip')
                    ->select('MAX(ip.num)')
                    ->from('BizDatasBundle:BMC\\InfosPerso', 'ip')
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getSingleScalarResult();
        $maxId++;

        return $maxId;
    }
}
```

If I do an echo on `$maxId`, it will print the correct ID to set.
But when Doctrine flushes, the ID is set to `NULL` in the query and I didn't find why.

If you've an idea.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's see:

You say that dumping `$maxId` returns the correct value, but if you look closely at the code you provided, you actually are not setting the value to `InfosPerso`. More likely you're missing `->setNum( $maxId )`.

And by the way, you can clearly see that in the SQL Query:

```
INSERT INTO InfosPerso (num...) // and the rest of your columns here
```

and right after that:

```
with params [null,...]
```

As you can see, you did not provide a value for the column.

And as a last note, if you're gonna generate the ID's by yourself, you can remove `GeneratedValue` annotation. Quote from [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies):

> NONE: Tells Doctrine that the identifiers are assigned (and thus generated) by your code. The assignment must take place before a new entity is passed to EntityManager#persist. NONE is the same as leaving off the @GeneratedValue entirely.

Comment: I use the `CUSTOM` Generated Value, which indicates to Doctrine to use an external class to generate the ID (`InfosPersoIdGenerator` for this case).

When I don't use the `GeneratedValue` and use the `setNum()` method, the result is the same...